# C# How do I convert a point to a vector2?

Tags: c#, vector, casting, point

I have a vector2 variable, I want to set it to a method that returns a point. Any clean way to convert that point to a vector2?

EDIT: I'm getting negative rep and question closed for this question.. I WAS much more specific at first but someone else edited it and made it less specific. It originally wasn't this vague..

EDIT: Reverted to original and more clear question to avoid confusion for anyone who may be reading in the future.

Comment: Make your own extension method

Comment: XNA - I thought I answered sooner but I guess it didn't go through, sorry.

EDIT: Anyway, looks like I'm makin a custom method for it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Create a extension like this:

```
public static class PointExt
{
    public static Vector2 ToVector2(this Point point)
    {
        return new Vector2(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but question is other way

Comment: Question asks for a function that "returns a point" which this does not

Answer (score 1):

You should use this extension method

```
 public static Point Vector2ToPoint(Vector2 vector2)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(
            (int)(vector2.X + 0.5f), (int)(vector2.Y + 0.5f));

        return pt;
    }
```

There are lots of methods [here](https://code.google.com/p/sbip/source/browse/trunk/SBIPFramework/src/Helper/XNATypesConverter.cs?r=161) that could be useful for you.

Comment: I doubt they've made an explicit cast.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance [They didn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2_members.aspx)

Comment: I have added the source.

Comment: Well the OP didn't say whether this is WPF or XNA.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class PointExt
{
    public static Vector2 ToVector2(this Point point)
    {
        return new Vector2(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question asks for a function that "returns a point" which this does not